# Three.JS throws error warning in console when calling camera.lookAt()

Tags: camera, three.js, scene

I have tried to solve it for 5 hours now. No luck.

I use a `fly control` for my scene.

I trying to make my camera look at an object after the object has been added to the scene as following:

```
var mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, morphTargets: true, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
var obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.6, 1.8, 0.6 ), mat );
obj.name = <some id>;
obj.castShadow = true;

obj.position.x = p.posX;
obj.position.y = p.posY;
obj.position.z = p.posZ;

obj.rotation.x = p.rotX;
obj.rotation.y = p.rotY;
obj.rotation.z = p.rotZ;

scene.add( obj );

//NOTE 1            
camera.position.set(obj.position.x-10, obj.position.y+10, obj.position.z-10);

var pos = obj.position.clone();

//NOTE 2                
camera.lookAt(pos); //with this line, a warning is shown in the console
```

The error that is shown is as following:

> THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog() WARNING: Could not find
>   vertex shader attribute 'position' to match BindAttributeLocation
>   request.

What is going on?

**BONUS PROBLEM**

Even if the position is changed at `NOTE 1` and the object is looked at at `NOTE 2`, when I start flying the scene turns black.

I have tried with an `orbitcontrol` as well and I get the same results.

Comment: It's not an error it's a warning. It's just basically telling you `gl.bindAttributeLocation(program, someLocation, "position")` was called but there is no attribute called "position". It's kind of a bogus warning because that's totally legit and arguably best practice WebGL. THREE.js chooses to print warning though as they may be helpful once in awhile. Seems like they should default to not printing the warnings IMO but I can see the argument for printing them.